# Best way to upgrade from debian squeeze to jessie

Tags: debian

I have an old dedicated server and want to upgrade it to the latest OS version.

I'm searching for the best way to upgrade from **Debian 6 Squeeze** => **Debian 8.6 Jessie**.

Comment: I believe [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-debian-wheezy-to-jessie-stable-release/) is probably what you are looking for. The steps should be similar

Answer (score 5):

First, keep in mind that things can break when upgrading from one Debian version to another. I have performed many upgrades and I have seen it going without a glitch, but also seen it resulting on an unworkable machine. I would advise you to first make an image of your current installation in case things go really wrong (a good tool for that is clonezilla - I use it all the time and it works great).

That being said, I would advise you to update from squeeze to wheezy first ([see link](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-debian-squeeze-to-wheezy)) and then from wheezy to jessie ([see link](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-debian-wheezy-to-jessie-stable-release/)).

Again, keep in mind this can go wrong and have an image of the installation made before upgrading.